# Prevent GC from disposing a WebSocket when the task is finished running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

I'm trying to maintain a list of WebSockets for a server which only needs to send messages to the client and not receive any replies. When the WebSocket is created initially all I want to do is just add the socket reference to a list for later use.

```
...

static Dictionary<int,WebSocket> wsDict = new Dictionary<int,WebSocket>();

...

private Task ProcessWS(AspNetWebSocketContext context)

{

    wsDict[id] = (context.WebSocket);
    ...

}
(Finishes running the method and returns)
```

The issue I'm having is that I believe GC is disposing of the WebSocket, so when I try to use it at a later time I receive 'System.ObjectDisposedException'. Is there any way of permanently stopping GC from disposing of the socket?

Edit:
Sorry for not being clear originally, the whole class which inherits ApiController is (as the name suggests) is a control. A client initiates the WebSocket via a GET request and  it calls the method above where it tries to store the socket into a dictionary (mapped to a int). The dictionary itself is Static.

It saves it into the Dict fine and in the debugger everything looks great. Its just literally disposing it after ProccessWS is complete and I can't seem to find a way to stop it. If I add a loop/sleep timer to the bottom of the ProcessWS it works fine - but thats not a viable solution.

The is a problem which originally I wasn't sure if it would be possible as each of the REST calls are stateless yet I need to maintain and overall list of all the connections which seems to contradict the original statement.

Comment: The way to prevent an object from being collected is to ensure it remains reachable. Unfortunately, you haven't provided enough context for anyone to understand why it's _not_ reachable in your scenario. If the `wsDict` remains reachable, then so too would any `WebSocket` instance reference stored within it. (BTW: you don't need that `if`...just always execute `wsDict[id] = context.WebSocket;`)  **See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: You probably need to have the client create a socket separately from the GET request, so that you can control the lifetime of the object. But until you provide a good code example, it's not possible to know for sure. Please note: the GC only disposes objects via their finalizer, and only if the object becomes unreachable. It is not clear from your question whether you are really seeing the GC dispose your object, or some other part of the code. That you can access the object later and receive the exception suggests that contrary to your title and post, it isn't the GC disposing your object

Comment: you should await Reading socket while socket is connected as mentiond by vTortola. because once the controls returns from ProcessWs, the socket gets disposed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to await reads while the WS is still connected:

```
public class WSHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(ProcessWS);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessWS(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
        WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;

        ...

        while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None)
                                                        .ConfigureAwait(false);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```